# Check if a file exists on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am trying to check if a file is on the server with the C# code behind of my ASP.NET web page. I know the file does exist as I put it on the server in a piece of code before hand. Can anyone see why it is not finding the file. This is the code:

```
wordDocName = "~/specifications/" + Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["projectSelected"]) + ".doc";
ViewState["wordDocName"] = wordDocName;
if (File.Exists(wordDocName))
{
    btnDownloadWordDoc.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    btnDownloadWordDoc.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Unix path conventions on Windows?

Comment: @GreenScreen: why do you convert your ViewState into an int? It will be converted back to a string and you have 2 conversions with the risk of a ConversionException.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

the file path should be physical not virtual. Use

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(wordDocName)))
```

Comment: Additional info on physical vs virtual: [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Comment: The answer, if written for vb.net, needs an additional 3rd, closing parenthesis.  I couldn't edit the answer with only one character so I am commenting.

Answer (score 2):

`File.Exists()` and probably everything else you want to do with the file will need a real Path.

Your `wordDocName` is a relative URL.

Simply use

```
string fileName = Server.MapPath(wordDocName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Server.MapPath("~/specifications/" + Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["projectSelected"]) + ".doc")
```

to get the fully-qualified path.  That should do the trick for ya.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Server.MapPath` e.g.

```
    wordDocName = Server.MapPath("~/specifications/" + Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["projectSelected"]) + ".doc");
    ViewState["wordDocName"] = wordDocName;
    if (File.Exists(wordDocName))
    {
        btnDownloadWordDoc.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnDownloadWordDoc.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this might not work if the directory holding the file is referenced by a junction/symbolic link. I have this case in my own application and if I put the REAL path to the file, File.Exists() returns true. But if I use Server.MapPath but the folder is in fact a junction to the folder, it seems to fail. Anyone experienced the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the path to a physical path with Server.MapPath(relativePath)

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))

wordDocName = "~/specifications/" + ViewState["projectSelected"] + ".doc";        
btnDownloadWordDoc.Visible = File.Exists(Server.MapPath(wordDocName));
```

Answer (score 0):

The character "`~`" is a special char in ASP.NET to get **virtual** path specifications and simply means "*root directory of the application*". Is is not understood by the .NET BCL like the `File` API and must be mapped first into a **physical** path with `Server.MapPath()` as others stated.

Answer (score -3):

`string docname="traintatkalantnoy.txt";`

`string a = (Server.MapPath(docname));
            if (File.Exists(a))`